# Why does this ternary operation causes memory growth

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

The following line causes memory growth (no releases, only one malloc line in instruments) when testing with mark generation feature of allocations instrument

```
- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title andImageNamed:(NSString *)imageName andButtonProperties:(NOZSKButtonNodeProperties *)buttonProperties
{
   ...
    textNode.text = buttonProperties.buttonTitleIsUppercase ? 
        [title uppercaseStringWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale] ] :  title;
   ...
}
```

Here is the code that calls it

```
NOZSKButtonNodeProperties *props = [self getThreeButtonProps];
...
props.buttonTitleIsUppercase = YES;
...

// this initializer is calling the above initializer by passing nil for imageName arg
NOZSKButtonNode *btn = [[NOZSKButtonNode alloc] initWithTitle:@"Play Again" andButtonProperties:props];
```

Comment: Because you don't have a surrounding autorelease pool that's being released at appropriate intervals?

Comment: How much memory are we talking about, bytes or MB?

Comment: Kilobytes: 396 KB for example

Comment: I put that uppercase to a separate line and now it does not show anymore. I dont know why it fixed the problem  `NSString *uppercasetitle = [title uppercaseStringWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale] ];`

Comment: Hot Licks. I am not, I thought ARC is taking care of it all.

Answer (score 1):

`-uppercaseStringWithLocale:` makes an upper-case copy of the `title` string.  This requires allocation.  And although you didn't show this, I assume `textNode` both retains its `text` property and has a wider scope than the `-initWithTitle:andImageNamed:andButtonProperties:` method and therefore continues to live afterwards.

Comment: Can you give an example like if you do like this and this, ARC won't clean up?

Answer (score 1):

Without more complete code it is not possible to be sure, but here is a guess in case it helps.

It sounds like you might be chasing a ghost. Are you seeing increasing memory due to this code *across* different iterations of your run loop?

Explanation: Even with ARC some memory is placed in the "autorelease pool" rather than being immediately deallocated when no longer required. This is an unfortunate legacy of MRC. ARC is able to avoid some uses of the autorelease pool and deallocate memory quicker, but not all uses.

The autorelease pool is typically emptied once per iteration of your main run loop. If you allocate and release a lot of memory in response to a single event, say in a long loop, it can be worth while wrapping the offending code in an `@autorelease { ... }` block which creates, and empties on exit, a local autorelease pool. This helps keep the peak memory usage down - it doesn't deallocate any more memory overall, it just does it cleanup sooner.

When you altered your code and saw an apparent improvement you may just have reorganised your code in a way more amenable to ARC's optimisations which reduce use of the autorelease pool, and so memory is deallocated sooner.

You only need to be concerned if (a) memory is increasing across multiple events or (b) you are hitting a too high peak memory use. Under ARC (a) should be rare, while (b) requires locating the source and wrapping it in an `@autorelease { ... }` block.

HTH

Comment: I need to hold on to my object created within a loop (they are SKNode objects that get placed on scene) so they are not like temporarily created objects that need to be released as soon as the loop block ends. I will upvote your answer but cannot accept it as the answer until I figure out exact cause. I understand more code is needed but i would have to post a lot and it would reveal too much about the project.

Comment: @Nihat - The code you've shown suggests it is intermediate strings which might be ending up in the auto release pool, not `SKNode`s. Also if you hold onto your objects, I.e. Keep a strong reference to them, then placing their creation within an `@autorelease` cannot make you lose them provided you store your strong reference within the same `@autorelease`. HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
textNode.text = buttonProperties.buttonTitleIsUppercase ? 
    [title uppercaseStringWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale] ] :  title;
```

When you write `[title uppercaseStringWithLocale:]`, this method has to create a new instance in order to change the given string to upper case. This is going to increase the memory usage of your program because this new string has to be allocated.
<strike>Also, it would have helped to know whether or not you are using ARC, because I don't think this should be an issue with ARC.</strike>

Comment: I know it creates a copy but I am using ARC, shouldn't it be taken care of?